# canvas.toDataURL() returns same dataURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I'm currently developing ionic app with firebase.
I'm trying to upload multiple files with resizing.

It is weired that when I call resize method input image is different but once I finish my uploading, it ends up uploading duplicated images(last image of array).

I `console.log`ed dataURL of it everytime it resize and found that DataURL is always the same.

following code is to upload multiple files.

```
    multipleUpload: function(key, folder, files, targetWidth) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var ct = Date.now();
    var urls = [];

    var recursive = function (n, args) {
      var arg = args[n];
      ImageService.resize(arg.file, targetWidth)
      .then(function(file) {
        upload(ct + '' + n + key, folder + '/' + key, file, CONFIG.MESSAGE.FILE_UPLOAD + (n + 1) + '번 파일')
        .then(function(url) {
          urls.push(url);
          if (++n < args.length) {
            recursive(n, args);
          } else {
            q.resolve(urls);
          }
        }), function(error) {
          q.reject(error);
        };
      })
    }
    recursive(0, files);

    return q.promise;
  },
```

Following code is resizing method

```
  resize: function(file, targetWidth) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    // Resizing Image
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.onload = function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = targetWidth;
      canvas.height = canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      // Data URL to BLOB
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(dataURL); // Returns same dataURL all the time.
      dataURLtoBlob(dataURL, Date.now())
      .then(function(blob) {
        q.resolve(blob);
      });
    };
    img.src = file;
    return q.promise;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I found one thing weird that it worked fine on ios but android.

I started to digging plugin options and disabled `allow-edit` then it works fine. I believe it is an issue from the plugin.